# How to assign a bitmap to a child which is an image view in a layout by considering View class?

Tags: android, view, bitmap, children

I have an app in which i want to assign a bitmap named original to an image view whose id is img1 in the layout  by taking the position of the image view in the layout(here it is child at position 0). When i click the save button,i want to assign bitmap named  original to image view whose id is img1 in the layout.I know we can assign by using ourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaptobeassigned). But in my app,my situation is to assign the bitmap original by means of View object child only.Please help me. My main class is

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.FrameLayout;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

      public class Test extends Activity
    {

   Button save;
  Bitmap original;
  FrameLayout frame;
  ImageView background;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
   save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
   frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);
   background=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
   background.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());
   original=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.parrot);
   save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
            View child=frame.getChildAt(0);
```

//Here i obtained image view as a child.But I do not know how to assign bitmap to it.
            //please help me how to write code here.

```
      }
  });

  }
   }
```

and my xml file is

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/vg"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/white" >   

    <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/frame"
    >

  <ImageView
android:id="@+id/img1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:scaleType="matrix"
/>

 </FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="save" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer.my main class is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Test extends Activity
{

Button save;
Bitmap original;
FrameLayout frame;
ImageView background;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);
background=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
background.setOnTouchListener(new myTouchListener());
original=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.parrot);
//background.setImageBitmap(original);
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ImageView child=(ImageView) frame.getChildAt(0); 
            child.setImageBitmap(original);



    }
});

 }
  }
```

and my xml is

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/vg"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/white" >   

 <FrameLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/frame"
 >

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/img1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:scaleType="matrix"
/>

</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="save" />
</LinearLayout>
```